# What's using all my storage? [__MutationMarker__]

Tags: google-app-engine

I deleted most of the entities in my app [~2M]. Yet the storage used has not fallen. 
I queried the stats for my app and found the following:

```
__________Kind Name____________|_Count_____|_Bytes_
Calendar                        32          26,688
DailyRollup                     367         815,815
_AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation    4           5,089
_AE_Pipeline_Barrier            135         394,242
_AE_Pipeline_Record             88          318,412
_AE_Pipeline_Slot               82          13,6608
_AhAdminXsrfToken_              1           658
_GAE_MR_MapreduceState          1           3,168
_GAE_MR_ShardState              32          38,152
__MutationMarker__              2,318,770   1,063,562,044
```

The first 2 Entity Kinds are created by me [0.08% of data] 
What is **__*MutationMarker*__** ? 
What is it doing? Why is it using so much space? 
Can I delete it ? 
 Thanks for any assistance. 
Mike

==============================================================================

Code to get the stats for each kind

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import stats

global_stat = stats.GlobalStat.all().get()
timestamp = global_stat.timestamp
kind_name = stats.KindStat.all().filter("timestamp =", timestamp).fetch(15)
kind_list = [stat.kind_name for stat in kind_name]

for kind in kind_list:
  print kind, 
  kind_stat = stats.KindStat().all().filter("kind_name =", kind).get()
  print kind_stat.count, kind_stat.bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutation Marker is a hidden entity that is used when migration data from one application ID to another application ID. It marks whether an entity has changed such that the entity will be copied during the "delta" phase of the next attempted migration.

This entity should not take up space that counts against your quota, however. What is your application ID?

Comment: Thanks, Ikai. <br> I did migrate the data from M/S to HR datastore. <br> My appId is http://whelanmike.appspot.com/ <br> <br> Cheers

Comment: Thanks, Ikai.  
    I migrated data from MS to HR datastore.
Then I deleted most of the old entities [in MS].

The appID for this is http://whelanmike.appspot.com/

There's obviously some problem with this MutationMarker entity in my app.


Cheers
Mike